# Check if value of one column exists in another column, put a value in another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a data frame like the following:

```
A B C D E
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1
a2 a1 c2 d2 e2
a3 a1 a2 d3 e3
a4 a1 a2 a3 e4
```

I want to create a new column with predefined values if a value found in other columns.
Something like this:

```
A B C D E F
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 NA
a2 a1 c2 d2 e2 in_B
a3 a1 a2 d3 e3 in_B, in_C
a4 a1 a2 a3 e4 in_B, in_C, in_D
```

The `in_B, in_C` could be other string of choice. If values present in multiple columns, then value of `F` would be multiple. Example, row 3 and 4 of column F (in row 3 there are two values and in row 4 there are three values). So far, I have tried a below:

```
DF.F=np.where(DF.A.isin(DF.B), DF.A,'in_B')
```

But it does not give expected result. Any help

Comment: With the output you gave, what was the string of choice?

Comment: The string could be 'X' if A present in B, 'Y' if present in C, 'Z' if present in D, so, X, Y if present in B and C, and  X, Y, Z if present in B, C and D. Not sure if it clarify enough.

Comment: No clear, please refer to your preferred output and explain to us how for example row 4 becomes  `a4 a1 a2 a3 e4 in_B, in_C, in_D`

Comment: In the new column, the value would be multiple if value of A exist in multiple columns. In row 4, the value of A exist in B, C and D. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### STEPS:

1. `Stack` the dataframe.
2. check for the `duplicate` values.
3. `unstack` to get the same structure back.
4. use `dot` to get the required result.

```
df['new_col'] = df.stack().duplicated().unstack().dot(
    'In ' + k.columns + ',').str.strip(',')
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
    A   B   C   D   E         new_col
0  a1  b1  c1  d1  e1                
1  a2  a1  c2  d2  e2            In B
2  a3  a1  a2  d3  e3       In B,In C
3  a4  a1  a2  a3  e4  In B,In C,In D
```